# Do you need to wrap the phrase "including X" with commas?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Do you need to wrap the phrase "including X" with commas? I was told that you had to, but I am not sure if it's true, because I don't think it's necessarily a parenthetical clause, at least it's not always the case.

For example:

> He made everyone cry including grandma by telling his life story.
>
> He made everyone cry, including grandma, by telling his life story.

Aren't both valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, using commas (or not) would be determined by if the information is nonrestrictive or restrictive.

But I can't imagine a situation where *everyone* would *not* necessarily include grandma. Otherwise, I'd expect it to read something like this:

> He made everyone ***except*** grandma cry by telling his story.

That version has no commas because grandma is being isolated from (restricting) the larger group. Note, too, the different location of *cry* in that particular construction.

---

So, practically speaking (even if not in terms of theory), I can't see commas *not* being used in that sentence.

In short, I would use:

> He made everyone cry, including grandma, by telling his life story.

---

On the other hand, I find both ***including*** *grandma* and *by telling* to be a bit unusual.

If I were writing the sentence, I would find the following (with commas) more natural:

> He made everyone cry, ***even*** grandma, ***when he told*** his story.